# Boost numeric_cast<> with a default value instead of an exception?

Tags: c++, boost

Whenever boost's `numeric_cast<>` conversion fails, it throws an exception. Is there a similar template in boost that lets me specify a default value instead, or is catching the exception the only thing I can do in this case?

I'm not too worried about the performance of all the extra exception handling, but I'd rather use a standard template than write useless wrapper functions. Besides, from past experience, I thought it's likely that boost actually has what I'm thinking of, and I simply haven't found it.

Comment: The point is that it *does* throw an exception.  If you don't want one, just cast.

Comment: nobugs: numeric\_cast detects overflow and underflow, while "just casting" won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `numeric_cast` function simply calls the [`boost::numeric::converter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/converter.html) template class with the default arguments. One of the arguments is [`OverflowHandler`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/converter_policies.html#oh), and the default value for that is [`def_overflow_handler`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/converter_policies.html#oh_def), but you can specify [`silent_overflow_handler`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/converter_policies.html#oh_silent) to suppress the exception instead.

Then specify the [`FloatToIntRounder`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/converter_policies.html#f2i) argument that will provide your desired default value if the input argument is outside your desired range. The argument is *normally* used for providing an integer for rounding from a floating-point type, but you can really use it for whatever you want. More information, plus code describing the sequence of events, at the [`converter` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/converter.html).

As far as I know, Boost doesn't have what you're thinking of, but it provides the facility for you to build it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class Target, class Source>
typename boost::numeric::converter<Target,Source>::result_type
numeric_cast_defaulted(Source arg, Target default_value = Target()) try {
  return boost::numeric_cast<Target>(Source);
}
catch (boost::bad_numeric_cast&) {
  return default_value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed on the boost mailing list several times, however, no unified solution has been accepted yet. You can use the following placeholder function until then, however, due to exception raising it's neither style nor efficiency-wise nice:

```
template<typename Target, typename Source>
  inline Target default_numeric_cast(Source arg, Target def)
{
    try {
        return numeric_cast<Target,Source>(arg);
    } catch (...) {
        return def;
    }
}
```

However, a custom-made solution would be waaay more efficient.