# static_cast with bounded types

Tags: c++

When you cast an int in short with a classic static_cast (or c cast), if the value is out of the short limits, the compiler will truncat the int.

For example:

```
int i = 70000;
short s = static_cast<short>(i);
std::cout << "s=" << s << std::endl;
```

Will display:

```
s=4464
```

I need a "inteligent" cast able to use the type limit and, in this case return 32767. Something like that:

```
template<class To, class From>
To bounded_cast(From value)
{
  if( value > std::numeric_limits<To>::max() )
  {
    return std::numeric_limits<To>::max();
  }
  if( value < std::numeric_limits<To>::min() )
  {
    return std::numeric_limits<To>::min();
  }
  return static_cast<To>(value);
}
```

This function works well with int, short and char, but need some improvments to works with double and float.

But is it not a reinvention of the wheel ?

Do you know an existing library to do that ?

***Edit:***

Thanks. The best solution I found is this one:

```
template<class To, class From>
To bounded_cast(From value)
{
  try
  {
    return boost::numeric::converter<To, From>::convert(value);
  }
  catch ( const boost::numeric::positive_overflow & )
  {
    return std::numeric_limits<To>::max();
  }
  catch ( const boost::numeric::negative_overflow & )
  {
    return std::numeric_limits<To>::min();
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put the answer in your original question. You are, however, allowed to post an answer to your own question. I encourage you to take your edit out of your question and put it in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at boost's [Numeric Conversion library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html). I think you'll need to define an [overflow policy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/numeric_converter_policy_classes.html#boost_numericconversion.numeric_converter_policy_classes.policy_overflowhandler) that truncates the source value to the target's legal range (but I haven't tried it). In all, it may take more code than your example above, but should be more robust if your requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Boost numeric_cast<> with a default value instead of an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993391/boost-numeric-cast-with-a-default-value-instead-of-an-exception) So question.

You can use std::numeric_list as your default value when an exception is thrown